# Javascript Image Preloader memory leak

Tags: javascript, ios, memory-leaks

I have a JS function to preload a set of images which are then stored in an array and eventually drawn on to canvas when triggered. I am having a few issues with memory sizes on iPad and older iPhones. Whereby once a set number of images has loaded the app grinds to a holt. Thereby making me think that the issue lies in the pre-loader.

If anyone is able to shed any light on this or point my in any direction I would appreciated it.

```
canvas.preload = function(images){

  var
  d = $.Deferred(),
  // Empty Array
  a = [];

  // For each image in batch
  _.each(images, function( val, i) {

    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function(){

      // Push Image and index into array
      a.push({image:this, index:i});

      // Sort this array by the index
      var sortedArray = _.sortBy(a, 'index');

      // When total batch is loaded return it
      if (a.length === images.length) {
        // Pluck just image from array
        d.resolve(_.pluck(sortedArray, 'image'));
      }

    }

    img.src = images[i];

  });

  return d;

} // preload();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is due to the memory limit set by mobile devices.

Your images might be **too big** for them. And for big it could be either **dimension wise or bite wise**. The problem is that they don't alert you in any way: **they simply never download them**.

The best approach in those cases is always provide with different assets depending on devices.
So for instance, if the client is using a mobile device, try to download a smaller version of the image.

Comment: Hi Stefano, thanks for your reply. I should have mentioned that I am serving up different sized assets depending on platform. 3 sizes total; Desktop, Tablet and Mobile.